# Reducing time complexity in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, time-complexity, big-o

I am building a simple hangman game using Javascript and wanted to know what the best way to optimise my code would be.

```
const Hangman = function (word, remainingGuesses) {
  this.word = word.toLowerCase().split("");
  this.remainingGuesses = remainingGuesses;
  this.guessedLetters = [];
};

Hangman.prototype.getPuzzle = function () {
  let puzzle = "";
  this.word.forEach((char) => {
    this.guessedLetters.includes(char) || char === " "
      ? (puzzle += char)
      : (puzzle += "*");
  });
  return puzzle;
};
```

At the moment as you can see from the above code, I am doing a `forEach` loop for `this.word` and then inside the `forEach` loop I am using `.includes()` to find whether a word has been guessed, if not then set the char to `*`.

At the moment I believe the time complexity of `O(n2)` due to the `includes()` inside the `forEach` what would be a better way to rewrite the `getPuzzle()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Set` for `guessedLetters` for constant time lookup:

```js
const Hangman = function (word, remainingGuesses) {
  this.word = word.toLowerCase().split("");
  this.remainingGuesses = remainingGuesses;
  this.guessedLetters = new Set(); // this is a Set now
};

Hangman.prototype.getPuzzle = function () {
  let puzzle = "";
  this.word.forEach((char) => {
    // use Set.has instead of Array.includes
    this.guessedLetters.has(char) || char === " "
      ? (puzzle += char)
      : (puzzle += "*");
  });
  return puzzle;
};
```

You can add a new guessed letter with `this.guessedLetters.add(char)`.

Comment: Yes, using a Set or hash is the right way to go for faster lookups (as opposed to repeated linear searches through an array). BUT, since strings are immutable, your forEach loop is STILL doing a lot of unnecessary work; every use of '+=' has to recreate the entire string over again. To avoid this, change the puzzle variable to an array, change "(puzzle += char)" to "puzzle.push(char)" (same for "*"), and return puzzle.join(''). This means that you build the string only once.

Comment: Very interesting and clean solution with the Set. I have one question though, isn't a simple object (map of key and value) even faster? The object would be something like this: { 'a': 'a', 'b': 'b' }, where 'a' and 'b' are the guessed letters.

Comment: Sets are generally faster than objects.

Comment: I got curious about this comparison because I always thought objects were faster. So I found a benchmark that says that objects are much faster than Sets and Maps. Sadly I couldn't find which operations were used to get those results. https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/5364/0/set-vs-object-vs-map